# Looping Shiny callModule only exports last value

Tags: r, loops, module, shiny

I am trying to build an app which; 1) calculates the number of boxes, based on a data.frame, 2) For each box, creates a UI and a corresponding module that will trigger events when the action buttons are clicked, using a subset of that data.frame.

If I am not being explicit enough; the app has *n* UI's and in each UI, *x* buttons. I want to loop `callModule` to create *n* server functions so when I click on action button in any given UI, I trigger an event specific to that UI.

The problem I am having is that the callModule function apparently does not duplicate itself in a for loop. Instead, I always get only the last id and dataframe (as if the callModule overwrites itself).

I hope I was explicit enough. Here is a MWE:

**server.R**

```
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source('modules.R')

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # dataframe filtered / updated 
  dtst <- reactive({
    iris[1:input$filter_d, ]
  })

  # number of items rendered
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    r <- tagList()
    for(k in 1:input$n){
      r[[k]] <- u_SimpleTaskView(id = k, d = dtst()[k, ]) # <- grab a subset or column of df
    }
    r
  })

  for(y in 1:isolate({input$n})){
    callModule(m_UpdateTask, id = y, d = dtst()[, y]) 
  }

})
```

**ui.R**

```
dheader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(title = "s")
dsidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("tst", tabName = "tst", icon = icon("bolt"))
  )
)

dbody <- dashboardBody(

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tst",
            numericInput("n", "number of ui and module pairs", value = 10), 
            numericInput("filter_d", "RANDOM FILTER", value = 100), 
            uiOutput("ui")
    )
  ) )

dashboardPagePlus(
  title = "s",
  header = dheader,
  sidebar = dsidebar,
  body = dbody

)
```

**modules.R**

```
u_SimpleTaskView <- function(id, d){
  ns <- NS(id)

  if(length(d) < 5){
    # nothing
  }else{
    renderUI({
      tagList(
        br(),
        HTML(paste0("<strong>Rows: </strong>", "xxxx")),
        numericInput("divider", label = "number of rows", value = 2),
        br(),
        actionButton("go", "go")
      )
    })
  }


}

m_UpdateTask <- function(input, output, session, d){

  observeEvent(input$go, {

    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        HTML(paste0("unique: ", length(unique(d))/input$divider ) )
      )
    )

  }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides not being really minimal (no need for libraries `shinydashboardPlus` or `shinydashboard`) there are a couple of issues with your code.

1. `renderUI` is a `server` function not a `UI` function
2. If you create controls in the module UI you have to use the namespace function, otherwise you cannot use them in your module server function.

---

As it is a bit too complicated for me to debug your code directly, let me give you an example from which you can see how to use modules in the way you wanted:

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)

mod_ui <- function(id, base_df) { ## 3
  ns <- NS(id) ## 1
  tagList(
    helpText(glue("The input parameter 'base_df' has {NROW(base_df)} rows.")),
    numericInput(ns("n"), "n:", 2),
    textOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

mod <- function(input, output, session) {
  get_nr <- reactive(input$n) ## 2
  output$out <- renderText(glue("Number selected: {get_nr()}"))
  return(list(get_nr = get_nr)) ## 4
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("n", "number of uis:", 2),
  uiOutput("uis"),
  textOutput("sum")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  handlers <- list()
  
  output$uis <- renderUI({
    ret <- lapply(seq.int(input$n), 
                  function(i) mod_ui(glue("mod_{i}"), 
                                     data.frame(x = seq.int(i)))) ## 5
    tagList(ret)
  })
  
  observe(
    handlers <<- lapply(seq.int(input$n), 
                        function(i) callModule(mod, glue("mod_{i}"))) ## 6
  )
  
  output$sum <- renderText({ ## 7
    req(length(handlers) > 0)
    m_sum <- sum(sapply(handlers, function(h) h$get_nr()))
    glue("Sum of all n: {m_sum}")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Explanation**

1. In `mod_ui` we define all the elements one module should have. note the use of `ns()` for the controls' ids to make use of the namespacing.
2. In `mod` (the module server function) we can access controls as we would in the main server function ( i.e. directly liek in `input$n`.
3. We can pass arguments to any of the module's functions (like `base_df`).
4. If we want to use some of the reactives in the main app, we shoudl return them from the modules server function.
5. In our main app we use a loop to create the desired number of modules.
6. We use an observer to store the handlers from the modules in a list
7. We can access the modules reactives via the handler which we defined earlier.

---

### Update 2021

`shiny 1.5.0` introduced an easier interface for modules. The code below uses this "new" interface:

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)

mod_ui <- function(id, base_df) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    helpText(glue("The input parameter 'base_df' has {NROW(base_df)} rows.")),
    numericInput(ns("n"), "n:", 2),
    textOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

mod <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      get_nr <- reactive(input$n)
      output$out <- renderText(glue("Number selected: {get_nr()}"))
      return(list(get_nr = get_nr))
    }
  ) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("n", "number of uis:", 2),
  uiOutput("uis"),
  textOutput("sum")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  handlers <- list()

  output$uis <- renderUI({
    ret <- lapply(seq.int(input$n), 
                  function(i) mod_ui(glue("mod_{i}"), 
                                     data.frame(x = seq.int(i))))
    tagList(ret)
  })

  observe({
    handlers <<- lapply(seq.int(input$n), 
                        function(i) mod(glue("mod_{i}")))
  })

  output$sum <- renderText({
    req(length(handlers) > 0)
    m_sum <- sum(sapply(handlers, function(h) {
     res <- h$get_nr()
     if(is.null(res)) {
       0
     } else {
       res
     } 
    }))
    glue("Sum of all n: {m_sum}")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your're right on the `renderUI` part but I have tried to update my code to your suggestions and get the same result. I am not sure if it is because my mod is "silent". I do not "run" anything until a button is pressed (I am not returning anything). Should I be "returning" something in the function?

Comment: I would replace the for loop by `lapply` because it could have something to do with the loop variable not evaluated at time but only in the end.

Comment: Yeah, it was the loop, mind-boggling how I spent so much time with this! Working now! thanks

Comment: It would be nice if the OP replaced the code with the new version of shiny module that uses `moduleServer` instead of `callModule`

Comment: Added the new syntax to my answer