# R Shiny: Can't access variables stored in a list in reactive element

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I would like to select one sample from my dataset in a dropdown menu.

As there are many samples to choose from, I would like to narrow down the selectable samples by selecting the values of additional data columns in checkbox dropdown menus.

I can successfully create the checkbox dropdown menus and and print the selections made there.

I am struggling with feeding these same selected values into the dropdown menu that chooses the sample. I want to make the choices of the selectInput reactive but can't access the variables the same way as inside renderText().

See comments in the code for where I am stuck.

Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


##################################
#### checkbox dropdown module ####
##################################

mod_ui_checkbox_dropdown_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("choice_dropdown"))
    
  )
}


mod_ui_checkbox_dropdown_server <- function(id, dropdown_label = "Items", menu_choices = c("item1", "item2", "item3"), dropdown_status = "default"){
  
  dropdownButton <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {
    
    status <- match.arg(status)
    # dropdown button content
    html_ul <- list(
      class = "dropdown-menu",
      style = "max-width: 300px;",
      #style = if (!is.null(width))
      #  paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),
      lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;")
    )
    # dropdown button appearance
    html_button <- list(
      class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
      style = "width: 100%; max-width: 300px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;",
      type = "button",
      `data-toggle` = "dropdown"
    )
    html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
    html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret", style = "margin-top: 8px;")))
    # final result
    tags$div(
      class = "dropdown",
      do.call(tags$button, html_button),
      do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
      tags$script(
        "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});")
    )
  }
  
  
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    
    # output$selected_items <- renderPrint({
    #   input$dropdown_checkboxes
    # })
    
    
    output$choice_dropdown <- renderUI({
      dropdownButton(
        label = dropdown_label, status = dropdown_status, width = "100%",
        actionButton(inputId = ns("all"), label = "all/none", class = "btn btn-sm", style = "margin-bottom: 8px;"),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = ns("dropdown_checkboxes"), label = NULL, choices = menu_choices, selected = menu_choices)
      )
    })
    
    
    
    
    # Select all / Unselect all
    observeEvent(input$all, {
      if (is.null(input$dropdown_checkboxes)) {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(
          session = session, inputId = "dropdown_checkboxes", selected = menu_choices
        )
      } else {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(
          session = session, inputId = "dropdown_checkboxes", selected = ""
        )
      }
    })
    
    
    # return selected values
    return(reactive(input$dropdown_checkboxes))
    
  })
}









##################
#### main app ####
##################

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  textOutput("text"),
  uiOutput("sample_dropdown"),
  #uiOutput("manual_checks"),
  br(),
  br(),
  uiOutput("sample_filters"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  data <- tibble::tibble("Sample ID" = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6"),
                         "Group" = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group3"),
                         "Name" = c("Aime", "Balthasar", "Charlotte", "Daniel", "Emilie", "Fiona"))
  
  ns <- session$ns
 
  
  # helper function. filters dataframe columns for only the entries listed in selected_values
  # selected_values is a list with an entry for each filter dropdown that holds a reactive vector with the selected items from each dropdown
  
  filter_selection <- function(data, selected_values){
    # loop through list by names of the list items
    for (val in names(selected_values)){
      if(!is.null(val)){
        data <- dplyr::filter(data, .data[[val]] %in% selected_values[[val]]())
      }
    }
    return(data)
  }
  
  ### select sample ###
  
  # get selectable samples from study data
  selectable_samples <- reactive({

##### HERE BE DRAGONS 
##### THIS DOES NOT WORK: When I try to access the values from the checkboxes here in this reactive element, I only get the empty list().
##### How do I make this reactive element respond to the selected values?

    ### ONLY PRINTS EMPTY LIST ###
    print(selected_values)
    ### THIS GIVES AN ERROR ###
    #print(selected_values$Name())
    
    data %>%
      
      # filter the choices based on the selected values here
      {if(length(selected_values) != 0) filter_selection(., selected_values) else .} %>%
      
      dplyr::select(any_of("Sample ID")) %>%
      unique() %>%
      pull() %>%
      sort()
   
  })
  
  
  
  output$sample_dropdown <- renderUI({
      selectInput("sample_dropdown", label = NULL, choices = selectable_samples())
  })
  
  
  
  
  ## ---- sample filters ##
  ## this dynamically creates checkbox dropdown menus for selected filter columns
  sample_filter_cols <-  c("Group", "Name")
  
  
  # create filter module UI elements
  output$sample_filters <- renderUI(
    sapply(sample_filter_cols, function(fav){
      mod_ui_checkbox_dropdown_ui(stringr::str_replace_all(fav, " ", "-")) #IDs don't like spaces
    })
  )
  
  # capture filter module outputs in list
  # solution using a list and observe() adapted from here
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802428/looping-shiny-callmodule-only-exports-last-value
  selected_values <- list()
  observe(
    selected_values <<- sapply(sample_filter_cols, function(x){

      choices <- data %>%
        select(any_of(x)) %>%
        unique() %>%
        pull() %>%
        sort()
        
      mod_ui_checkbox_dropdown_server(stringr::str_replace_all(x, " ", "-"), dropdown_label =  x, menu_choices = choices)
    }, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
  )
  
 
##### THIS WORKS: I can access the selected values of the filter columns here and print them as text.
##### So why won't this propagate to the reactive element above?

output$text <- renderText(paste("selected values:",
                                 paste(selected_values$Name(), collapse = " "),
                                 paste(selected_values$Group(), collapse = " ")
                                 ))



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I built it without modules and it is a little bit simple, but it works.

I changed the 2nd SAMPLE ID -> to `Sample 3` because I need to prove one sample with more than one group.

I hope this can help you.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
require(tibble)


data_read <<- 
  tibble::tibble(
    "Sample ID" = c("Sample1", "Sample3", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6"),
        "Group" = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group3"),
         "Name" = c("Aime", "Balthasar", "Charlotte", "Daniel", "Emilie", "Fiona"))

if (interactive()) {
  
  
  reactive_data <- reactiveValues(
    data_all = data_read,
    data_sample_filter = data_read[0,],
    vector_groups = NULL,
    group_selected = c(),
    vector_names = NULL,
    
  )
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "sample_dropdown",
      label = NULL,
      choices = data_read$`Sample ID` %>% unique 
      ),
    uiOutput("group_dropdown"),
    uiOutput("names_dropdown"),
    
    verbatimTextOutput("texto"),
    tableOutput("table")
    
  )
  
  
  server <- function(input, output) {

    observe({
      
      data_filter_group <<-
        data_read %>% 
        filter(
          `Sample ID` %in% input$sample_dropdown
        )
      
      
      output$group_dropdown <- renderUI({
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "group_dropdown",
          label   = "select group(s)", 
          choices = isolate(reactive_data$vector_groups),
          options = 
            list(
              `actions-box` = TRUE
            ), 
          multiple = TRUE
        )
      })
      
      # Change reactive values
      reactive_data$data_sample_filter <- data_filter_group
      reactive_data$vector_groups <-    data_filter_group$Group %>% unique

      
    },
    label = "group_dropdown UI"
    )
    
    
    observe({
      # save reactive values input group
      reactive_data$group_selected <- input[["group_dropdown"]]
      
      
      data_filter_names <<-
        isolate(reactive_data$data_sample_filter) %>%
        filter(
          Group %in% isolate(reactive_data$group_selected)
        )
      
      # Change reactive values
      reactive_data$vector_names <-    data_filter_names$Name %>% unique
      
      
      output$names_dropdown <- renderUI({
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "names_dropdown",
          label = "select group(s)", 
          choices = isolate(reactive_data$vector_names),
          options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE), 
          multiple = TRUE
        )
      })
      
    },
    label = "names_dropdown UI"
    )
   
  
    
    # example  all data output
    output$table <- 
    renderTable({
      data_read
    })
    
    output$texto <-
      renderText({
        paste("selected values:\n",
              input$sample_dropdown,"\n\t",
              paste( input[["group_dropdown"]],sep="" ,collapse = "\n\t"),"\n\t\t",
              paste( input[["names_dropdown"]],sep="" ,collapse = "\n \t\t")
        )
      })

    
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to replace all filter() with dplyr::filter() but this is working. I had no idea the pickerInput existed. This looks very neat! I need this to work the other way around though. I need to select group and names first, then these choices need to narrow down the samples that appear in the samples dropdown. hardcoding group_dropdown and names_dropdown also won't do as there may be a variable number of dropdowns. This is where my problem arises I think. As I am using sapply() the outputs of all n dropdowns go into a selected_values list which itself is not a reactive element.

Comment: EDIT: Tinkered with this in the morning and was able to come up with something much cleaner. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Thanks to Yeyo's suggestion of using pickerInput I was able to do away with my monstrosity of a custom widget module and get this to work nicely with much less code!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)


#' Helper Function
#'
#' @description helper function to filter the choices of a dropdown menu based on selected data
#'
#' @return character vector with choices that remain after filtering the data
#' 
#' @param data data frame to be filtered
#' @param choice_col name of the column that holds all possible values for the dropdown menu. e.g. if the dropdown menu chooses sample ids, this may be the "Sample ID" column
#' @param filter_selections list with selected values from all filter dropdown menus. e.g. list("Group" = c("group1", "group2), "Names" = c("Aime", "Balthasar")), will produce all samples that are in these two groups and belong to these two names.
#'
#' @noRd


filter_choices <- function(data, choice_col, filter_selections){
  
  choices <- data
  
  for (filter_col in names(filter_selections)){
    choices <- choices %>%
      dplyr::filter(., .data[[filter_col]] %in% filter_selections[[filter_col]])
  }
  
  choices <- choices %>%
    dplyr::select(any_of(choice_col)) %>%
    unique() %>%
    pull() %>%
    sort()
  
  return(choices)
}





##################
#### main app ####
##################


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  uiOutput("sample_dropdown"),
  h3("Filters"),
  uiOutput("sample_filters")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  data <- tibble::tibble("Sample ID" = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6"),
                         "Group" = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group3", "group3"),
                         "Name" = c("Aime", "Balthasar", "Charlotte", "Daniel", "Emilie", "Fiona"))
  
  

  ### dropdown to select a sample from the data ###
  selectable_samples <- reactive({
    filter_choices(data, choice_col = "Sample ID", filter_selections = selected_values())
  })
  
  output$sample_dropdown <- renderUI({
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput("sample_dropdown", label = "Select Sample", choices = selectable_samples())
  })
  
  
  ### ---- dropdowns to narrow down choices of samples I am interested in ###
  # specify which data columns you want to be able to filter by
  sample_filter_cols <-  c("Group", "Name")

  # create picker UI elements for these columns
  output$sample_filters <- renderUI(
    div(
      lapply(sample_filter_cols, function(x){
        choices <- data %>%
          select(any_of(x)) %>%
          unique() %>%
          pull() %>%
          sort()
        shinyWidgets::pickerInput(stringr::str_replace_all(x, " ", "-"),
                                  label = x,
                                  choices = choices,
                                  multiple = TRUE,
                                  selected = choices,
                                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
      })
    )
  )
  
  # collect output of filter dropdown menus in a reactive list
  selected_values <- reactive({
    sapply(sample_filter_cols, function(x){
      input[[stringr::str_replace_all(x, " ", "-")]]
    }, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
  })
  
 
}
 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```